# Trying to use set-var in haproxy config to set to a string

Tags: haproxy

I would like to set a variable in the frontend block of haproxy so it can be used in the backend block.

I have:

```
   http-request set-var(txn.backend) "host.azurewebsites.net",lower if { path -m str /xc }
```

But haproxy cannot parse this and errors with:

```
[ALERT]    (1) : config : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:35] : error detected in frontend 'http' while parsing 'http-request set-var(txn.backend)' rule : unknown fetch method 'host.azurewebsites.net'.
```

This seems like a really simple thing to do but I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, found it in the docs: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#7.3.2-str

so:

```
http-request set-var(txn.backend) str("host.azurewebsites.net"),lower if { path -m str /xc }
```